# Does Websphere 8.5 with Java 8 selected as runtime supports JSF 1.1?

Tags: jsf, java-8, websphere

We have application running JSF 1.1. Until these days we were using Java 6 deployed in WAS 7, now we are migrating to WAS 8.5 with Java 8 as runtime. Please advise where JSF 1.1 is supported with combo of Java8 with WAS 8.5.

Comment: Try... but even better.... upgrade to 2.3

Comment: If the ancient JSF impl is  part of your app and not the server, isn't it you that determines if it's supported?

Comment: Check this table it maybe can be usefull [Versions Table link](https://myfaces.apache.org/compatibility.html)